# Adding missing dates to a time series from a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, missing-data

I have a monthly time series of a variable 'GWL' but with several missing dates.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'1218_29_0.csv')
df.head(5)

    date        GWL
0   15/01/2001  9.73
1   15/08/2001  10.55
2   15/11/2001  11.65
3   15/01/2002  9.72
4   15/04/2002  9.92
```

I have tried to follow other posts but none of them deal with a database in CSV format.

How can I add the missing dates (months) and fill their value by Nan?

Comment: Set index to date and then reindex with a date range set to the ides.

Comment: Can you please show me this in more detail? I am a novice on python

Comment: Can you provide your data in data-frame constructor format?

Comment: I'll try (I dont really know how), but I need a solution for a CSV database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I load using:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''date        GWL
15/01/2001  9.73
15/08/2001  10.55
15/11/2001  11.65
15/01/2002  9.72
15/04/2002  9.92'''), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python', parse_dates=['date'])
```

What you need to do in your code is just pass the `parse_dates=['date']` parameter to your `pd.read_csv`. Don't pass the other stuff. I need to use `io.StringIO` because you won't provide your data in a constructor format.

This yields:

```
        date    GWL
0 2001-01-15   9.73
1 2001-08-15  10.55
2 2001-11-15  11.65
3 2002-01-15   9.72
4 2002-04-15   9.92
```

Construct an Ides-centred monthly date range:

```
months = df['date'] - pd.offsets.MonthBegin()
d_range = pd.date_range(months.min(), months.max(), freq='M')
d_range = d_range - pd.offsets.MonthBegin() + pd.offsets.Day(14)
```

Reindex:

```
>>> df.set_index('date').reindex(d_range)
              GWL
2001-01-15   9.73
2001-02-15    NaN
2001-03-15    NaN
2001-04-15    NaN
2001-05-15    NaN
2001-06-15    NaN
2001-07-15    NaN
2001-08-15  10.55
2001-09-15    NaN
2001-10-15    NaN
2001-11-15  11.65
2001-12-15    NaN
2002-01-15   9.72
2002-02-15    NaN
2002-03-15    NaN
```

Comment: I want to give you my data in contruct format, it's just i dont know how...    following your request I got the error: ` NameError: name 'months' is not defined`

Comment: @Bouram Copy the output of `df.to_dict()`. Paste.

Comment: I got the error: ` NameError: name 'months' is not defined`

Comment: My apologies, I missed a line when copying

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem on this line but for the Reindex line, a new error appeared: 'ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis'

Comment: You have multiple observations in the same month. What does your data actually look like?

Comment: Thank you very much, That's right, I used the following code to resolve that: df.drop_duplicates(subset=['date'], keep=False,inplace=True)